# SSH Network error: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I was trying to setup sublime text editor to connect via sftp on my server but was getting connection timeout all the time. 
I found a solution and followed this article :
https://superuser.com/a/957666

They suggested to change the server config to accept a mac algorithm used by the client by adding this `hmac-sha1` on `KexAlgorithms`. 
So in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I changed:

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

to

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,hmac-sha1
```

And now i try to login on my server and i get `Network error: Connection refused`

How can i regain access to my server? My server is hosted on kimsufy.

Comment: You mean you changed your ssh servers setup, restarted the daemon _without_ keeping a session open? Then you need to use your hosters VNC access, or whatever they offer.

Comment: This is not a question for Stack Overflow.. Try it out on http://superuser.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @arkascha: Perhaps there should be a failoverflow? :)

Comment: It always is a very good idea to have _two_ sessions open when working on the sshd. As clearly stated in the documentation an existing session does _not_ get interrupted when you change your ssh servers configuration. Thus you can try your changes whilst still having a session to revert changes that did not work out as expected.

Comment: Besides most hosters offer some kind of vnc server which allows you to access your virtual host as if sitting in front of the terminal with a keyboard attached. You can use any vnc client for that, you just need the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to ask Kimsufi support for them to reset your sshd_config and restart sshd.

Then though to fix your timeout problem, a solution could be to use a SSH tunnel and configure it to send "keep-alive" packets (basically null packets periodically to keep the session active).

Comment: "reset your sshd_config"? How that? You mean you give them your root password? That is not meant serious, or is it?